# Common ground between battery and AC/DC adapter

Tags: power-supply, batteries, dc

Is it possible to connect an AC/DC power adapter's ground (-) to a battery's negative side?

I am powering a car radio with a 12V AC adapter. That works fine. However, if the radio loses power, it also loses it's programmed FM stations etc. There is a separate cable to provide constant +12 V. from the car battery, but there is only one "-".

Would it work if I connect both the AC/DC "-" and the battery's "-" together to the car radio "-" lead, and the "+" sides of the adapter and the battery to their respective leads?

Or would this fry my battery, my adapter, my radio, or burn down the house :-) , or just plainly not work?

Edit:

- I was thinkinkg of any small cheap 12V battery. Probably non-rechargeable. Maintaining settings memory should draw very little power.
- I have no idea whether the 2 separate +12V leads are eventually shorted inside the car radio or not.
- The main difference in my setup from the normal use in a car is that in a car, these 2 power leads get the same voltage (from the single car battery). In my case, they would get a different voltage (possibly up to 2-3 volts of difference?).

Comment: we need to know what is the type of your battery. Is that LiPoIon ? or lead acide gell?

Comment: You generally need to make sure that the + of the battery and the + of the AC adapter are not directly shorted. If they are a direct connection you may want to place an appropriate diode in series with the battery to the radio and another in series with the + of the battery to the radio.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it would work. If you think about it for a moment, that's exactly how it's wired when it's used in the car.

Regarding the additional issues raised in your edit:

Inside the radio, there are two kinds of electrical loads: those that get swtiched on and off with the ignition, and those that need continuous power, such as the clock and the memory for the frequency presets.

If the radio works without any power applied to the "unswitched" power input, that means there's some sort of diode (or equivalent) that powers the unswitched loads from the "switched" power input.

In a car, there are other loads on the unswitched power bus, and the radio designers would not have wanted to power those loads through the diode inside the radio, so there will also be a second diode that prevents this. (You should be able to use a multimeter to verify this.)

Therefore, if you replace the switched power with an AC power supply, there's no way that the AC power supply can try to charge the battery you have attached to the unswitched power input. Everything will be fine. In fact, if you *want* to use a rechargable battery, you'll have to provide an external charging path.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Sure, that's how it's used in the car, but the car has a rechargeable battery and the car's alternator has circuitry designed to charge that battery.  If the radio shorts those two +12V terminals (which would make sense), and you tried connecting it this way, you'd be running current into a non-rechargeable battery, which could cause damage and/or fire.  See @Kaz's answer for more details.

Comment: @nitwit: You misread the question. It isn't about connecting the two +12V leads together at all. It's about whether you can tie the negative lead of the AC power supply and the negative lead of the backup battery together. The positive leads remain separate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from your answer that the radio has separate + terminals for the battery and AC adapter, so that the only thing in question is the common - .

If that is the case, it is reasonable to expect that the radio already has circuitry which takes care of the simultaneous operation on two voltage sources. That is, it is designed to use the AC adapter as a backup to preserve the radio settings while the car battery is disconnected (for which it is necessary to have some overlap: AC power comes online before car battery goes offline).

What you don't want is for the AC adapter to try charging the battery or for the battery to send a current through the AC adapter. The easiest way to prevent that is with diodes which act as valves, allowing current to flow only in one direction. A diode on each supply can ensure that there is no back flow into the weaker voltage source. The radio probably has something like this, but check the user manual if it has anything to say.

The common return isn't a problem, and it is inevitable: it's the only practical way to design the radio to run off two voltage sources simultaneously. Electricity passes through the radio's complex circuitry from either one of these sources, whose currents are mixed together. On the return side, there is no way to distinguish which electricity came from where.  There is just one return current. Even if two minus terminals were provided by the radio, internally they would connect to the same node.

The only thing that can be done is to connect the common return to the return of each voltage source. That way any current which came from the car battery returns to the car battery and any current which came from the AC adapter returns to the adapter. But both currents pass through identical pathways inside the radio. If we were to trace the course of any single electron, we might find that an electron which came from the battery ends up returning to the AC adapter. However, such an electron will be balanced by another one going the opposite way. The current returning to either voltage source is precisely equivalent to the current coming from that source.

You're right to be concerned about connecting the grounds of two separate electrical systems, such as a car and an AC adapter. In general, it's not the sort of thing that you do blindly. Two electrical systems  could have common return that are not at the same electrical potential, causing a current to flow between them if they are bridged (far above and beyond the expected return currents that the connection is expected to provide). That could even cause a safety issue if one, or both of those systems contain high voltages.

In this case, it doesn't matter. The car is a self-contained system that isn't actually connected to any external ground. It sits on four insulating rubber tires and usually doesn't touch anything. It's "ground" is just a common return to the - terminal of the battery. (Usually. Historically there have been cars with opposite conventions: + is common). The AC adapter is also probably isolated (at least if it is a transformer-based one rather than a switcher). The negative return line only returns current to the secondary winding of that transformer. Even if the AC adapter's return *is* connected to the power mains return, or even to the ground via a third prong, it is not harmful to ground the car in this manner. No unwanted current will flow through that ground because the car has not other circuit to anything that might be connected to the power mains.